# Azure AD B2C Invitation link using msal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js, identity-experience-framework

I am using [@azure/msal-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular) library in my Angular application (SPA).
Now we need to add a B2C custom policy to send the invitation to the user on their email id to signup.

I found [Invitation custom policy Sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite), but it is using .net to generate the token and the URL to be sent to the user email. I am using the same thing by replacing the necessary details and give it a try.

I want to achieve the generation of token and link in msal. Can someone share the needful to achieve this?

Front-end = Angular 7
Back-end = Java 8 (Azure Function Apps using java)

> EDIT

As mentioned by Tom, I have tried to create the JWT token on Java using jjwt. But what I still need is to how to get the private key related to the generated policy key in Identity experience framework. Please share the thoughts which help me achieve this using Java.

Comment: Do you have a chance to check my update?

Answer (score 1):

The .net code in the sample you shared generates JWT token with a private certificate, then B2C valiate the signuature of this token.

It makes no sense to generate token at client side for security reason. If you do that, your private key will be public. You should always generate token at server side.

So what you needs is a server side api to build token and link for you, then your angular code visit the API. You can just use the .net sample. If you prefer to JS, then use node.js with [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) npm package

**Update:**

Regarding how to get priviate key on Azure Web App, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-ssl-cert-load

You need to upload the private certificate, then make it accessible. 
Azure places the specified certificates in the Current User\My store for most pricing tiers, but if your app is running on the Isolated tier (i.e. app runs in an App Service Environment), you may need to check in the Local Machine\My store instead.

You can also [load the certificate from file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-ssl-cert-load#load-certificate-from-file).

Comment: Well, for the backend we use Java. So I am looking for some solution there.
I have also updated the question with these details.

Comment: @ForamkumarParekh Have updated my answer, check it out.